# Select first n words of each line of a file

Tags: awk, sed

Using sed or awk, I want to select the first n words of each line of a file.

I have a file with three lines, say

```
one two three four
one two three four
one two three four
```

and I want the output file to be the first, say, two words of each sentence:

```
one two
one two
one two
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: How do you define a *word*? How many words in `I'm going asap to the U.S.A. !` for instance in your definition?

Comment: sed 's/[^ ]*//3g' file

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
awk 'NF=2' file
one two
one two
one two
```

but depending on your `awk` version, your mileage may vary...